# php mongodb - can't get upsert working

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm running the following code and it works great, if no record exists it creates a new one. What I'm trying to do is modify this query so that the 'v' field also increases +1 but I'm not having any luck. Can someone help me out?

```
            $result = $collection->update(
                array('k'=>md5(SITE_ID.'-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])),
                array('$set'=>
                    array(
                        'k'=>md5(SITE_ID.'-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']),                                                                   'st'=>SITE_ID, 
                        'ur'=>$_GET['u'],                                                
                        'ts'=>time(),
                        'dt'=>date('Ymd'), 
                        'ur'=>$_GET['p'],
                        'v'=>1
                    ),
                    array(
                        '$inc' => array('v' => 1)
                    ),
                ),
                array('upsert'=>true)
            );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put both the `$set` and the `$inc` in a single object:

```
$result = $collection->update(
    array('k'=>md5(SITE_ID.'-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])),
    array(
        '$set'=> array(
                'k'=>md5(SITE_ID.'-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']),                                                                   'st'=>SITE_ID, 
                'ur'=>$_GET['u'],                                                
                'ts'=>time(),
                'dt'=>date('Ymd'), 
                'ur'=>$_GET['p']
            ),
        '$inc' => array('v' => 1)
    ),
    array('upsert'=>true)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $inc modifier liek:

```
{ $inc : { field : value } }
```

So in your case:

```
$result = $collection->update(
    array('k'=>md5(SITE_ID.'-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])),
    array('$set'=>
        array(
            'k'=>md5(SITE_ID.'-'.$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']),                                                                   'st'=>SITE_ID, 
            'ur'=>$_GET['u'],                                                
            'ts'=>time(),
            'dt'=>date('Ymd'), 
            'ur'=>$_GET['p'],
            array('$inc' => array('v' => 1))
        ),
    ),
    array('upsert'=>true)
);
```

I just saw you're actually using the field though the example above should work.

Here's an example in the PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php#example-1470