# Adding lock before insertion to MongoDB in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm looking for a way to add a kind of readers writers lock in php before inserting document to mondodb, in order to prevent insertion of duplicate documents. Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: Mongo automatically lock db for write of each single doc (see the concurrency: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/). Are you having some issues?

Comment: Why won't unique indexes work?

Answer (score 0):

What would you lock on? Either you want to create a unique index, or use the upsert functionality.

See this answer for usage of upsert: [php mongodb - can't get upsert working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298402/php-mongodb-cant-get-upsert-working)